# In WordPress how to assign a new custom user role after registering, based on domain of email used for registering

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns

I want to redirect newly registered users to a custom page based on the domain the email users are using when registering.

I'm thinking of doing this by assigning a custom role to users based on their domain name and redirecting users with that role.

For example, someone registers with someone@domainx.com
They get the role: domainx

I can use a code to redirect roles to certain pages.
But I have no clue what code to use to create these custom roles and assign them to these users.

Comment: In your function that redirects them, use the [`add_role()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/) function to add the new role (it won't add duplicates).

Comment: The redirect should happen just one time, after registration, or it needs to happen every time?

Comment: Would need that for everytime they login. I've now settled with; register form that gives user that register on that form a role. Redirect users with that role. But of course it would be nicer if I don't need any plugins, and can just do it with the normal login/register form of WordPress